# Magento show product from processing order

Tags: php, magento

The below code gives me an "`item`" array and not the `productname`. I don't know how to get the `productname`. This is the complete code.

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('status', 'processing')
->addAttributeToSelect('customer_email')
->addAttributeToSelect('status')
;
foreach ($orders as $order) {
$email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
$customername = $order->getCustomerName();
$product = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementID($order_id);
                    $items = $order->getAllItems();
                    $itemcount=count($items);
                    $name=array();
                    $sku=array();
                    $ids=array();
                    $qty=array();
                    foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
                    {
                       $name[]=$item->getName();
                       $sku[]=$item->getSku();
                       $ids[]=$item->getProductId();
                       $qty[]=$item->getQtyToInvoice();
                    }
echo  $order->getId() . ": " . $order->getStatus() . ": " . $email . ": " . $customername .  ": " . $name . "<br />";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
$item->getProduct()->getName()
```

If that doesn't work try with :

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($order->getStoreId())->load($item->getProductId());
$name = $product->getName();
```

Comment: Both are not working. I get with last one: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductId() on a non-object in /home/gaveaktie/domains/gaveactie.nl/public_html/magazijnplanning.php on line 13